# UPDATE and Increment column value POD

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to sum/add another value to the actual value in the database but this is not working. Any suggestions?

```
$suplies=15;
$user_id="100234";

$sql = "UPDATE table SET suplies=suplies+".$suplies." WHERE user_id=?";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':suplies'=>$suplies,':user_id'=>$user_id));
```

Comment: you're using different placeholders

Comment: UPDATE table SET suplies=suplies+ ? WHERE user_id=?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the named placeholder all through out.

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET suplies = suplies + :suplies WHERE user_id = :user_id";
```

Comment: Thanks but is giving me this error: invalid parameter number mixed named and positional parameters :/